# Sort a python dictionary by a specific function applied to its keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

Sorting dictionary with a numpy based function applied to its keys using `np.argsort`.

The following works but seems like too many steps; is there a simpler way?

Assume my final sorting function will be more complicated than the abstracted `n/m` shown here

```
import numpy as np

def get_sorted_dic(dictionary):

    keys = list(dictionary.keys())

    m, n = np.array(keys).T

    order = np.argsort(n/m).tolist()

    keyz = [keys[i] for i in order]

    return dict([(key, dictionary[key]) for key in keyz])

dic = {(7, 13): 'third', (9, 5): 'first', (27, 49): 'second'}

print(get_sorted_dic(dic))
```

which does return the correctly sorted dictionary `{(9, 5): 'first', (27, 49): 'second', (7, 13): 'third'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `sorted` function:

```py
dic = {(7, 13): 'third', (9, 5): 'first', (27, 49): 'second'}

dic_sorted = {k: dic[k] for k in sorted(dic.keys(), key=lambda t: t[1] / t[0])}
print(dic_sorted)
```

```
{(9, 5): 'first', (27, 49): 'second', (7, 13): 'third'}
```

Just replace `lambda` function with your *sorting function*.

Comment: This *looks shorter*, but is it actually fewer steps?

Comment: @uhoh Yes, compared to what you have. This doesn't involve intermediate steps with `ndarrays` and `lists`.

Comment: The reason I've written it this way is that dividing one array by another using numpy is often much faster than dividing one pair of numbers at a time in an iterated fashion, but I see now that I keep converting to lists, so I probably loose that advantage.

Comment: ya okay this is probably going to be better, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also sort `items()` directly, then apply `dict()`:

```
>>> dict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[0][1] / x[0][0]))
{(9, 5): 'first', (27, 49): 'second', (7, 13): 'third'}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a lot to learn; I can't tell if this actually ends up doing something different under the hood than writing it as a dictionary comprehension as shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62344926/3904031), or if it ends up doing almost the same thing. I'll do some tests, it will be a learning experience for me!